# Quoting a published paper

Tags: publishing

I was reading a preprint on archives (not yet published), and in the introduction the authors say "Following X in [ref]..." and go on to set up the problem. When I went to [ref], it turns out the authors of the preprint actually take three paragraphs *word for word* from X and include them in their introduction.

Is this appropriate? Just saying "Following X...." makes it okay? To me, it still looks like plagiarism.

Comment: This is not a math question. Try academia.SE.

Comment: In such a case, it is probably better to write "Quoting X" instead of "following X".